# KMS key policy to allow Step Function state machine to use encrypted SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-sam, amazon-kms

I have Encrypted SNS topic with KMS key. Here is KMS policy:

```
    Type: 'AWS::KMS::Key'
    Properties:
      Description: Key for SNS Encryption
      Enabled: true
      EnableKeyRotation: true
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: KmsKeyPolicy
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowDFX5AdminPermissionSet
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Ref ParamKMSKeyAdministratorUserRoleArn
            Action:
              - kms:Create*
              - kms:Describe*
              - kms:Enable*
              - kms:List*
              - kms:Put*
              - kms:Update*
              - kms:Revoke*
              - kms:Disable*
              - kms:Get*
              - kms:Delete*
              - kms:TagResource
              - kms:UntagResource
              - kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion
              - kms:CancelKeyDeletion
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: AllowAccountPoliciesToUseKey
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - states.amazonaws.com
                - sns.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - kms:Encrypt
              - kms:Decrypt
              - kms:DescribeKey
              - kms:GenerateDataKey
              - kms:ReEncrypt*
            Resource: '*'
```

My state machine role has appropriate permissions:

```
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:Encrypt
                  - kms:ReEncrypt*
                  - kms:Decrypt
                  - kms:GenerateDataKey*
                Resource: !Ref ParamKmsKeyArn
```

However, my state machine is giving me a following error: **User: arn:aws:sts::190565753270:assumed-role/dfx5-health-monitoring-dev-StepFun-StepFunctionRole-kMolFlKjZ3lh/HxHgpfIkpnjBOOhbdJevmlLNhdAkSNhL is not authorized to perform: kms:GenerateDataKey on resource: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:190565753270:key/c5697944-70f3-4806-b94a-0e081826ee25 because no resource-based policy allows the kms:GenerateDataKey action**

This error is telling me that my state machine role has not KMS permissions but it is there. I guess the problem will be with KMS policy. Any ideas please?

Comment: You need to give the step function role permission to use the key in the key policy. The easiest way to do this is to add a [default statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-default.html#key-policy-default-allow-root-enable-iam).

Comment: yea but i want to follow least privilege principe so i want to define that stepfunction and the SNS will be the only ones who can use the key

Comment: Ok, you just need to change the account arn to the role arn.

Answer (score 0):

As Olakunle indicated, you must include the IAM role that the state machine is using. Some services send directly to SNS, but Step functions is not one of them (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-key-management.html)
But a few points:

- If you directly give permissions to an IAM role in the KMS key policy, you do not need to give permissions in the IAM policy.  This is effectively the same as in any other resource policy, except that with KMS, you must give permissions in the Key Policy, it cannot only be done in the IAM Policy.

  - IF you give permissions to root, `arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:root`, you are not granting all roles permission, but you are delegating access to the key to IAM, which means then you give access by adding permissions in the IAM role policy (but only to the permissions you permit in the key policy).
- In this case you do not grant permissions to the Service.  The IAM Role is the principal that needs permissions.  If you want to restrict access to it being used with a specific service, then you need a condition to ensure that it is done VIA the service, and within that region.  For example, here is how you would do it in JSON.  I included both the section for granting the role access, and if one of the services that send directly to SNS (per the link above) was to be given access.

  ```
   {
       "Sid": "AllowAccountPoliciesToUseKey",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::190565753270:role/YourStateMachineRoleName"
       },
       "Action": [
           "kms:CreateGrant",
           "kms:Encrypt",
           "kms:Decrypt",
           "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
           "kms:ReEncrypt*"
       ],
       "Resource": "*",
       "Condition": {
           "StringEquals": {
               "kms:ViaService": [
                   "sns.REGION.amazonaws.com",
                   "states.REGION.amazonaws.com"
               ]
           }
       }
   },
   {
       "Sid": "Permit Local Account Services to Utilize the Key",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
           "Service": [
               "events.amazonaws.com",
               "cloudwatch.amazonaws.com",
               "s3.amazonaws.com"
           ]
       },
       "Action": [
           "kms:Decrypt",
           "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
       ],
       "Resource": "*"
   },
  ```